# Async Method Call

Tags: c#, .net

How can I call a method asynchronously ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to call a Visual C# method asynchronously:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315582

Answer (score 4):

You should probably use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` ([ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx))

Answer (score 3):

I guess the BackgroundWork is the easiest way to perform async operations.

Comment: BackgroundWorker is by far the quickest, easiest and least error prone method of not blocking your UI with a long running operation...if you're new to threading take baby steps and use this.

Comment: of course, it's the BackgroundWorker
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx